# CSS transition - tilting test-tube containing liquid

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-shapes

I have a simple CSS3 transition that involves a test tube, containing liquid, being tilted 60 degrees to the right.

Of course, liquid always stays on the horizontal plane, and it's this effect I'm having trouble with. I do have it working in a fashion, but the liquid's transition is far from convincing.

The idea was to simply rotate the liquid element, which is a child of the tube element, by the same but opposite degree, so -60. So the net, visual effect is the liquid stays at rotation 0deg. The liquid element has adequate width to allow for this rotation without showing white space.

**Code Pen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sIDtp (currently has only -moz prefixes, no -webkit)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='tube'><div></div></div>
  <div id='tube_bottom'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div, button { display: block; position: relative; }
#container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: -moz-transform 1s
}
#container.transition { moz-transform: rotate(60deg); }
#tube {
  border: solid 6px red;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tube_bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15%;
  border: solid 6px red;
  background: blue;
}
#tube div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -175px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 85%;
  top: 30%;
  background: blue;
  transition: -moz-transform 1s, top 1s;
}
#container.transition #tube div { moz-transform: rotate(-60deg); top: 70%; }
```

As you can see, I'm having to also modify the `top` property, which isn't ideal and tells me I'm probably not going about this the right way. It almost looks as if the liquid element is failing to rotate about its central point (which I believe is the default value for `transform-origin`.

Can anyone give me some tips as to how to make this transition look natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Different approach :** How about skewing the water?

This tube is made with :

- one div and 2 pseudo elements
- transform skew and rotate
- box-shadows

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wq7wqn1s/)** (no vendor prefixes)

*HTML :*

```
<div class="tube"></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.tube {
    border: solid 6px red;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom:none;
    width:50px;
    height:180px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    transition:transform 1s;
}
.tube:after, .tube:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
}
.tube:after {
    top:100%;
    left:-6px;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    border: solid 6px red;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px -30px 0px -6px blue, 0px -50px 0px -6px blue;
}
.tube:before {
    bottom:0;
    height: 100px;
    width:50px;
    z-index:-1;
    transition:transform 1s;
}
.tube:hover {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.tube:hover:before {
    transform: skewY(-60deg);
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how, on hover, to get the water to the edge of the tube, as though it were poised to drip out?

Comment: Also, and finally, what controls the level of water in the (pre-hover) tube? I can't quite see how to modify to make the tube more full or more empty, i.e. a hither/lower level of water.

Comment: @Utkanos it is the height of the `:after` pseudo element check this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wq7wqn1s/4/

Answer (score 4):

Since the width perspective of the tube increases as it turns, the effect speed of the tilting liquid should be inversely proportional, slower when it turns, and faster when it gets back...

I got a better looking effect by setting a different transition speed for turn, and turn back:

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGkDr)

```
#tube div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -175px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 85%;
  top: 30%;
  background: blue;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s, top 0.5s;
}
#container.transition #tube div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s, top 1.4s;
  top: 70%;
}
```

Though it could still get some improvements... (Sorry, I changed it all to `-webkit-`)

But perhaps you should consider using `animation` and `@keyframes`, so you could set specific values on each percentage of the transition.

Comment: Thanks for this - interesting details. I accepted the other answer just because it looked a bit better and used pseudo content, but +1 all the same.